# CSS3 animation move x,y using CSS grid class

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am using a grid absolute position of my tile elements using css such as .row1,.col1 .. .row6,.col6.
If I need to move a tile say from .row6,.col6 to .row2,col2 using CSS3 GPU accelerated transitions and transformation

what is the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using translate3d() should do the trick with the last argument fixed to zero.

Position the tile elements in the top corner (0, 0) or whatever the offset is using CSS.

Make a function to move each tile element to its position (I assumed px, but that can change):

```
function moveIt(element, xpos, ypos) {
    var move = ("translate3d( " + xpos + "px, " + ypos + "px, 0 )");

    element.style.webkitTransform = move;
    element.style.MozTransform = move;
    element.style.msTransform = move;
    element.style.OTransform = move;
    element.style.transform = move;
}
```

Now call that function on each tile with default or saved settings to set the tiles in place.

After this is done, you simply pass the element (lets call it "el") and the new desired position to moveIt:

```
// pretending each grid section is 50px, since row1col1 is (0, 0)
moveIt(el, 50, 50);
```

You can change the inputs to object properties or array members depending on how you are holding the information.